# Node.js: Crypto signature is inconsistent (different with every test)

Tags: javascript, node.js, signature, cryptojs

I'm trying to sign a payload and recreate the expected signature in the documentation of a service documented here: https://paybis.readme.io/reference/partner-api#signing-requests

My implementation of the signature is:

```
const signRequest = (privateKey: Buffer) => {

    const verifiableData = '{"event":"VERIFICATION_STATUS_UPDATED","data":{"partnerUserId":"e18fb964-fd9a-4de7-96c4-1lclszzd","status":"started"},"timestamp":1654073212}'

    const signature = crypto.sign(
        'sha512',
        Buffer.from(verifiableData),
        {
            key: privateKey,
            padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING,
        },
    );

    return signature.toString("base64");
}
```

And my test:

```
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './private.key'));

const signature = signRequest(privateKey);
const signature2 = signRequest(privateKey);

expect(signature).to.equal(signature2); //FAILS
```

Where the private key is formatted as such:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtJWQWnZJqbbxz1wNr3Dn/9I43z4Ddm/jd4G+PCkNGYXcqVqX
...
ukzH0Cx/iuONcUrYtpirM9ZMotfyyl4xO0Hc9bD/I97xn93GOvKFBkV9l7hW
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

No matter what I do, the signature is not consistent (aka. varies with every attempt)

Can anyone pinpoint what I might be doing wrong?

I tried using a string as the verifiable body, saving the key as a .pem file, instantiating the private key as a string, and passing it as both Buffer and string to the function.

Comment: RSA-PSS is non-deterministic but according to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/can-rsa-pss-signing-be-made-deterministic-without-loss-of-security) it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Interesting! So the signature is meant to be different every time and it can still be verified with the public key? I'll adjust my tests and check

Answer (score 0):

As stated in one of the comments, the answer is that RSA-PSS is non-deterministic, so the signature will *not* be the same by design.

However, when trying to verify any of these different correct signatures with crypto.verify, it does verify as expected:

```
it(`Can create correctly encrypt body`, async function () {
        const privateKey = process.env.PAYBIS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY!;

        const publicKey = KEY1;

        const wrongPublicKey = KEY2;

        const requestBody = { ... };

        const signature = signRequest(requestBody, privateKey); // Signature here is always different

        const verified = verifySignature(requestBody, signature, publicKey);
        const verifiedFalse = verifySignature(requestBody, signature, wrongPublicKey); 

        expect(verified).to.equal(true, 'Could not verify correct signature'); //Correctly outputs true

        expect(verifiedFalse).to.equal(false, 'Verified incorrect signature'); //Correctly outputs false
    });
```